# Optimization of high number of parameters in R

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to optimize linearly an accuracy of prediction in R, and I'm getting stuck at finding a convergence and a convenient answer.

My idea is the following : I have a set of 32 parameters which I want to optimize. These 32 parameters are randomly drawn from a normal distribution using 'rnorm'.

```
linCoeff <- rnorm(32,0,5)
```

(linCoeff as for linear coefficients).

These 32 parameters are combined in the following way :

```
myVal <-  (((clSigm*lCoeff[1])+lCoeff[2])*data[,1])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[3])+lCoeff[4])*data[,2])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[5])+lCoeff[6])*data[,3])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[7])+lCoeff[8])*data[,4])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[9])+lCoeff[10])*data[,5])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[11])+lCoeff[12])*data[,6])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[13])+lCoeff[14])*data[,7])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[15])+lCoeff[16])*data[,8])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[17])+lCoeff[18])*data[,9])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[19])+lCoeff[20])*data[,10])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[21])+lCoeff[22])*data[,11])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[23])+lCoeff[24])*data[,12])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[25])+lCoeff[26])*data[,13])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[27])+lCoeff[28])*data[,14])*data$indDV1+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[29])+lCoeff[30])*data[,15])*data$indDV2+
          ((clSigm*lCoeff[31])+lCoeff[32])
```

Where I have :

- clSigm, which is a fixed parameter;
- data[,i], which are the values on my data.frame I want to sum.

It has, in the end, the form of a sum of 16 elements, which gives me a numerical value : 'myVal'.
I then apply an activation function, which gives

- -1 if 'myVal' is >0 and
- +1 if 'myVal' is <0.

I then compare it to my input (which is a list of -1 and +1) and output the Balanced Accuracy.

I want to optimize linearly those 32 parameters to find the maximum BACC, but using conventional R methods doesn't give me probant results, as I never converge...

To give the example, the function I give to optim is :

```
retrieveVal <- function(lCoeff,data){
  clSigm <- 1/(1+exp(.5-(data$acc)))
  myVal <- (((clSigm*lCoeff[1])+lCoeff[2])*data[,1])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[3])+lCoeff[4])*data[,2])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[5])+lCoeff[6])*data[,3])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[7])+lCoeff[8])*data[,4])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[9])+lCoeff[10])*data[,5])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[11])+lCoeff[12])*data[,6])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[13])+lCoeff[14])*data[,7])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[15])+lCoeff[16])*data[,8])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[17])+lCoeff[18])*data[,9])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[19])+lCoeff[20])*data[,10])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[21])+lCoeff[22])*data[,11])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[23])+lCoeff[24])*data[,12])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[25])+lCoeff[26])*data[,13])+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[27])+lCoeff[28])*data[,14])*data$indDV1+
          (((clSigm*lCoeff[29])+lCoeff[30])*data[,15])*data$indDV2+
          ((clSigm*lCoeff[31])+lCoeff[32])
  act <- c(lapply(myVal,FUN=activate))
  return(-BACC(inp,act))
}
```

Then:

```
optim(par=linCoeff,fn=retrieveVal,data=myData)
```

If anyone can help here, I'm all hearing!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a different optimizer? I.e. the package `rgenoud` or `RcppDE` are usually better than `optim`. I'd do some tests for you with these packages myself, but since you've omitted any values for the `data` the example isn't really reproducible.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your answer ! you can consider that the values of every columns of the data lies in the [-3;+3] range, taken from a normal distribution (difficult to give all the dataset, but the values are near the distribution).
You can even drop off the 14 & 15th term in tries, there are some scaling factor not so useful at first.

But at least, many many thanks, I'll try those 2 packages and come back!